# How do I add a background image to LayoutDocumentPane?

Tags: c#, wpf, background, avalondock

I have created a `Resource` for the `ImageBrush`, see below, but I do not know how I would add it to the AvalonDock `LayoutDocumentPane`. I want to add it to the pane because I want to have a logo in the background, but `LayoutDocumentPane` covers the `Window` background.

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="LogoBitmap" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/myLibrary;component/myImages/myBigLogo.PNG"/>
<ImageBrush x:Key="LogoImage" ImageSource="{StaticResource LogoBitmap}"/>
```

Right now, I have the following:

```
<ad:DockingManager x:Name="dockManager" >
    <ad:LayoutRoot>
    <ad:LayoutPanel x:Name="myLayoutPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ad:LayoutAnchorablePane x:Name="myLayoutAnchorablePane"  DockWidth="400"/>
        <ad:LayoutDocumentPane x:Name="myDocumentPane"/>
    </ad:LayoutPanel>
    </ad:LayoutRoot>
</ad:DockingManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a method of setting a background image that works for my use case, but I am using a very simple AvalonDock configuration so I'm not sure if it will work for you.

This will set the image for the entire dock control, I was not able to find any way to set a background at any level lower than this.

```
<xcad:DockingManager x:Name="dockingManager">
        <xcad:DockingManager.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/Images/MDIBACKGROUNDIMAGE.png"/>
        </xcad:DockingManager.Background>
        <xcad:LayoutRoot>
            <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                    <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane >
                        <xcad:LayoutDocument>
                            <views:MyForm></views:MyForm>
                        </xcad:LayoutDocument>
                    </xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                </xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>                    
            </xcad:LayoutPanel>
        </xcad:LayoutRoot>
    </xcad:DockingManager>
```